# Add blur on container in flutter

Tags: containers, flutter-layout, blur

Good Morning.
I am trying to add blur to a container that will receive a label.
After reading a little about BackdropFilter, I was able to add it to the container. But it got that aspect.
Is it possible to add a Radius in blur?

I tried to create as follows, but it didn't work as expected.

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))
  ),
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        top: 0,
          child: BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 15, sigmaY: 15),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white54,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))
            ),
            width: 90,
            height: 45,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 15, 10),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.timer, color: Colors.white),
            Text(
              '11:50',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the shade by wrapping your `Container` inside a `ClipRRect` nested inside a `SizedBox` having the same size as your `Container` :

```
SizedBox(
  width: 90,
  height: 45,
  child: ClipRRect(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  top: 0,
                    child: BackdropFilter(
                    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 15, sigmaY: 15),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white54,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))
                      ),
                      width: 90,
                      height: 45,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 15, 10),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.timer, color: Colors.white),
                      Text('11:50',),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
```

I also removed the parent `Container` as it'll be no longer needed.